# Google datastore "search" like auto complete

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I understand GQL does not handle the LIKE operator, so how would I do auto complete, for example, I'm storing "People" with a "Name" and I have a box that I enter "Nig". How would I look for all people who's name matches what was typed and not just starts with?

Assuming I already have all the handling code to pass the content of the box to the back end, I'm just wondering how to do the data mine.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create autocomplete with GAE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795814/how-to-create-autocomplete-with-gae)

Comment: You'll find your answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795814/how-to-create-autocomplete-with-gae

Comment: actually, its not possible with datastore. the linked "duplicate" only covers "start with" which OP said isnt wanted

Comment: When users type "an" in a search box for names, they do not expect to see "Stan" and "Michelangelo" in the results.

Comment: but you would expect to see "mark antony smith"?? I was looking at "CONTAINS" which the datastore is supposed to handle with GQL, but the PHP API does not. It's a bit of a bottom.

Comment: You need to use the Text Search API for this.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Datastore queries do not support [arbitrary substring matches](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries) (such as the `CONTAINS` operator in SQL). You can do prefix matching by executing range queries.

If you want full-text search capabilities and are running in App Engine, check out the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/).